# Identical declaration and type compiler errors. (arg of type xyz* is incompatible with parameter of type xyz*)

Tags: c++, methods

Working to try and create a basic class here.

**Header file**

```
namespace Ogre
{
    class Vector3;
    class SceneManager;
    class Entity;
    class Quaternion;
}

class RayCasting
{
public:
    bool RayCastFromPoint(
        const Ogre::Vector3 &point, 
        const Ogre::Vector3 &normal, 
        Ogre::Vector3 &result, 
        Ogre::SceneManager& scnMgrRef);

private:
    void GetMeshInformation(
        Ogre::Entity* entity,
        Ogre::Vector3* vertices,
        size_t &indexCount,
        unsigned long* indices,
        const Ogre::Vector3& position,
        const Ogre::Quaternion& orient,
        const Ogre::Vector3& scale
    );
};
```

**Source file**

```
#include "RayCasting.h"

#include <OGRE/OgreMath.h>
#include <OgreRay.h>
#include <OgreSceneManager.h>
#include <OgreEntity.h>
#include <OgreSceneNode.h>
#include <OgreNode.h>
#include <OgreMath.h>
#include <OgreSubMesh.h>
#include <OgreSubEntity.h>
#include <OgreMesh.h>
#include <OGRE/OgreVector3.h>

bool RayCasting::RayCastFromPoint(
    const Ogre::Vector3 & point, 
    const Ogre::Vector3 & normal, 
    Ogre::Vector3 & result, 
    Ogre::SceneManager& scnMgrRef)
{
    // get the entity to check
    Ogre::Entity *collEntity = static_cast<Ogre::Entity*>(rayQueryResult[index].movable);

    // mesh data to retrieve         
    size_t indexCount;
    Ogre::Vector3* vertices = new Ogre::Vector3();
    unsigned long* indices;

    // get the mesh information
    GetMeshInformation(collEntity, vertices, indexCount, indices,
        collEntity->getParentNode()->_getDerivedPosition()      // Returns a const Vector3
        collEntity->getParentNode()->_getDerivedOrientation(),  // Returns a const Vector3
        collEntity->getParentNode()->_getDerivedScale());       // Returns a const Vector3
    ... 
}

void RayCasting::GetMeshInformation(
    Ogre::Entity * entity, 
    Ogre::Vector3* vertices, 
    size_t & indexCount, 
    unsigned long * indices, 
    const Ogre::Vector3 & position, 
    const Ogre::Quaternion & orient, 
    const Ogre::Vector3 & scale)
{
    ...
}
```

... Indicates irrelevant implementation details.

**Problem 1**
Both of the methods defined in RayCasting throw an E0147 error stating

```
declaration is incompatible with "bool RayCasting::RayCastFromPoint(const Ogre::Vector3 &point, const Ogre::Vector3 &normal, Ogre::Vector3 &result, Ogre::SceneManager &scnMgrRef)" (declared at line 20 of "E:\_PROGRAMMING\GEA-term2\Ogre_Projects\Tutorials2\Ogre3DProjectTemplate\RayCasting.h")    Ogre3DProjectTemplate   E:\_PROGRAMMING\GEA-term2\Ogre_Projects\Tutorials2\Ogre3DProjectTemplate\RayCasting.cpp 29  
`
```

and

```
declaration is incompatible with "void RayCasting::GetMeshInformation(Ogre::Entity *entity, Ogre::Vector3 *vertices, size_t &indexCount, unsigned long *indices, const Ogre::Vector3 &position, const Ogre::Quaternion &orient, const Ogre::Vector3 &scale)" (declared at line 27 of "E:\_PROGRAMMING\GEA-term2\Ogre_Projects\Tutorials2\Ogre3DProjectTemplate\RayCasting.h")   Ogre3DProjectTemplate   E:\_PROGRAMMING\GEA-term2\Ogre_Projects\Tutorials2\Ogre3DProjectTemplate\RayCasting.cpp 140
```

**Problem 2**
GetMeshInformation(... , vertices, ...) throws an E0167 error stating that

```
cannot convert to incomplete class "const Ogre::Vector3"    Ogre3DProjectTemplate   E:\_PROGRAMMING\GEA-term2\Ogre_Projects\Tutorials2\Ogre3DProjectTemplate\RayCasting.cpp 91
```

**Problem 3**
Further more, the GetMeshInformation(... , ...->_GetDerivedPosition(), ...) line generates an E0515 error stating

```
*"cannot convert to incomplete class const Ogre::Vector3"*, despite the include being present in the Source file. The scale() method also throws this error.
```

My question put simply is:

What. in the hell. is happening.

Comment: 1) Please copy-paste the messages, instead of paraphrasing them, in addition to providing [mcve]. 2) Header contains the declaration `void GetMeshInformation(..., Ogre::Vector3* vertices, ...)`, while defintion is `void RayCasting::GetMeshInformation(..., Ogre::Vector3*& vertices, ...)` (similar difference for `indices`).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius

Hey, sorry. I've pasted the messages, This should be minimal and complete but likely unverifiable without Ogre.

I've made the change in 2, can't believe that slipped by me but this issue remains

Comment: Still not [mcve] (please read the link). For instance, some errors hint at the classes you forward-declared, not being defined at point of usage. So, even if the definitions are in `OGRE/OgreVector3.h`, it's unclear whether those definitions are being made in `Ogre` namespace, where they are forward-declared in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently all issues with forward declaring Ogre::Vectorn's within headers can be solved by just giving up and including OgreMath.h in the header file.